# Is every closed interval domain, continuous rational function equal to a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, rational-functions

Given any 2 non zero polynomials with real coefficients $\mathbf Pn(x)$ and non-constant $\mathbf Pd(x)$ forming the rational function $\mathbf f(x)$ = $\mathbf Pn(x)$ / $\mathbf Pd(x)$.

 Restrict its domain $\mathbb R$ to a closed interval $\mathbb I$ such that $\mathbf f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb I$.

1. Is there for every such function $\mathbf f(x)$ a polynomial $\mathbf P(x)$ with real coefficients such that for any $\mathbf x$ $\in$ $\mathbb I$, $\mathbf f(x)$ = $\mathbf P(x)$?
2. Is there for no non-trivial such functions $\mathbf f(x)$ a polynomial $\mathbf P(x)$ with real coefficient such that for any $\mathbf x$ $\in$ $\mathbb I$, $\mathbf f(x)$ = $\mathbf P(x)$??

Context: I'm working on interpolation/regression curves, that is I'm trying to identify families of curves with or without certain features.
Here I'm wondering if there's any loss of generality from working with polynomials VS rational functions when we consider only finite intervals and continuous curves: no trivial line of reasoning come to my mind.

Comment: Even on a finite interval, rational functions are different from polynomials, and unless $Pd|Pn$ then the resulting rational function cannot be equal to a polynomial, so there is some loss of generality. The biggest differences between the two is that rational functions can be constant at infinity and they can also have poles, which polynomials cannot possibly mimic through the entire range of $f$ (even when infinite order). Now, if all you're trying to do is pass a curve through a set of points where you know $f$ is bounded, then it doesn't really matter which one you use.

Comment: There does not exist such a polynomial, except for the trivial case when $\mathbf Pd(x) \mid \mathbf Pn(x)$. Suppose $\,\mathbf Pn / \mathbf Pd = \mathbf P\,$ on $\mathbb I$, then $\,\mathbf Pn \cdot \mathbf P - \mathbf Pd = 0\,$ on $\,\mathbb I\,$, so $\,\mathbf Pn \cdot \mathbf P - \mathbf Pd\,$ has infinitely many roots and therefore must be the zero polynomial $\,\mathbf Pn \cdot \mathbf P - \mathbf Pd \equiv 0 \iff  \mathbf Pd = \mathbf Pn \cdot \mathbf P\,$.

Comment: DinosaurEgg Ty for the feedback. I considered the Pd|Pn case among the trivial ones. Infinity isn't part of a closed interval and poles would determine a discontinuity. So these cases are already excluded by my question. No, I'm not trying to just interpolate: I'm looking for the simplest class of functions with certain features.

Comment: dxiv Ty for the feedback. Let me study it a little (btw why commenting and not answering?). As a first impression I don't get why you write Pn/Pd=P => Pn*P-Pd=0. Shouldn't it be Pd*P-Pn=0 (not that it seems it'd make any difference. BTW n=numerator, d=denominator)? Most importantly for your argument: why should it (a polynomial) have infinitely many roots? does it depend on our arbitrarily large/small interval?

Comment: dxiv I think I get what you mean. Since f(x) must be equal to P(x), the polynomial Pd*P must be equal to the polynomial Pn for every point in the interval. And that implies that the curve PdP-Pn goes to 0 infinitely often. Mmm very nice... let me think another while to see if I'm conviced.

Comment: dxiv Sorry but I'm not convinced. If Pd*P-Pn is the zero polynomial in the interval, doesn't seem to imply that f(x) or P(x) are zero polynomials over that interval.

Comment: @Lorenzo Sorry, there is an obvious typo in my first comment, and $Pn \cdot P - Pd$ should be $Pd \cdot P - Pn$, instead. $\,$ "*doesn't seem to imply that f(x) or P(x) are zero polynomials*" $\,$ No, it doesn't. What it *does* imply is that $Pd \cdot P - Pn$ is the zero polynomial, which in turn implies that $Pn = Pd \cdot P$ and therefore $Pd \mid Pn$.

Comment: @dxiv But that's true only for the values included in the interval. So how can we conclude that Pd|Pn (therefore implying that f(x) is a polynomial from the start) if we know that only the values that f(x) assumes in the interval are equal to those of P(x)?
Is that because from a Taylor series perspective of f(x), the error term wouldn't generally be zero outside the neighborhood of a point in the arbitrarily large interval where the series is centered? But why should Taylor polynomials be the only good candidates for this P(x)?

Comment: @Lorenzo This has nothing to do with Taylor series, it's a fundamental property of polynomials. A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots $\implies$ any non-zero polynomial has finitely many roots $\implies$ a polynomial with infinitely many roots is identically zero. A non trivial interval $\mathbb I$ contains infinitely many points, so if $Pd \cdot P - Pn = 0$ on $\mathbb I$ then it must be the zero polynomial, so $Pd \cdot P - Pn \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry but that's just what you wrote in your previous comment: I seem to be missing some points in your reasoning. Yet I guess with your support I found a proof: 
1) an n-degree polynomial's n+k derivative (k=1, 2,...) is 0. 2) A rational function f(x) of the kind defined by the question has non-zero derivatives of every order in the interval I 3) 2 functions equal in a closed infinite interval I have the same derivative of every order in I (except possibly the limit points).
4) Ergo no polynomial can have equal values to f(x) in I. Thanks.

Comment: @Lorenzo Not sure which points you are missing, but the one I outlined is the simple, direct proof. Your line of proof can be made to work, but it is unnecessarily complicated and, as written, incomplete. This is about an algebraic property of rational functions, and resorting to calculus and derivatives overcomplicates it. Besides some statements ("*a rational function ... has non-zero derivatives of every order in the interval*") have to be proven, not just stated, and the proof of that comes down to the same fundamental property that a non-zero polynomial has only finitely many roots.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry but sometimes I seem to miss simple things when they're not expressed in a way my brain is wired to understand. I guess the need for synthesis in the comments doesn't help too (why just commenting and not answering?). Maybe if you can suggest me a reference to some basic theorems to build your proof I'll have a look, but for my needs, my "incomplete" proof is more than fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lorenzo Posted as an answer with (hopefully) all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there for every such function $\mathbf f(x)$ a polynomial $\mathbf P(x)$ with real coefficients such that for any $\mathbf x$ $\in$ $\mathbb I$, $\mathbf f(x)$ = $\mathbf P(x)$?
> 2. Is there for no non-trivial such functions $\mathbf f(x)$ a polynomial $\mathbf P(x)$ with real coefficient such that for any $\mathbf x$ $\in$ $\mathbb I$, $\mathbf f(x)$ = $\mathbf P(x)$??

There does not exist such a polynomial, except for the trivial case when the rational function is itself a polynomial, which answers both questions above in the negative.

This follows from the stronger statement: if a real (or complex) rational function equals a polynomial at infinitely many points then the rational function is identically equal to the polynomial on $\,\mathbb R\,$ (or $\,\mathbb C\,$), and this can only happen when the denominator of the rational function divides the numerator as a polynomial, so the rational function reduces to the quotient polynomial after the division.

Let $\,f(x) = \frac{P_n(x)}{P_d(x)}\,$ be a rational function, and let $T$ be an infinite set of values such that $\,P_d(t) \ne 0\,$ and $\,f(t) = P(t)\,$ $\;\forall t \in T\,$ for some polynomial $\,P(x)\,$.

Let the polynomial $\,R(x) = P_d(x) \cdot P(x) - P_n(x)\,$, then for $\,\forall t \in T\,$, and given that $\,P_d(t) \ne 0\,$:

$$
R(t) = P_d(t) \cdot P(t) - P_n(t) = P_d(t) \cdot \left(P(t) - \frac{P_n(t)}{P_d(t)}\right) = P_d(t) \cdot \big(P(t) - f(t)\big) = 0
$$

Therefore, each $\,t \in T\,$ is a root of $\,R(x)\,$. But a polynomial of degree $\,n \ge 1\,$ has at most $\,n\,$ roots by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) (fundamental theorem of algebra) or, in other words, the only polynomial with infinitely many roots is the zero polynomial. It follows that $\,R(x)\,$ is the zero polynomial, so $\,P_d(x) \cdot P(x) - P_n(x) = 0$ $\iff\;P_n(x) = P_d(x) \cdot P(x)\,$. This proves that $\,P_d(x) \mid P_n(x)\,$, so the rational function $\,\frac{P_n(x)}{P_d(x)}\,$ simplifies to a polynomial.

Comment: Perfectly clear now. Furthermore, you prove that not only on a compact interval this is true. On an infinite set of isolated points too, polynomials' values can't be equal to rational functions' ones.